# Webpack HMR: Does not watch changes to external packages in /node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, lerna

I have a project on React + Webpack 2. Since recently, there was a need to divide the project into modules. I decided to use Monorepo with Lerna. But I have caused a lot of problems. One of the main problem is that the changes that I make to the linked package do not cause automatic assembly.

I think that I did not take something into account. Tell me what could be the problem?

My config:

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/master/internals/webpack

Comment: share your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/master/internals/webpack

Forgot to specify that I'm using a react-boilerplate. You can see the config here.